# Suggestion required for max width of a form

Tags: forms, readability, responsive

My team is building a form builder tool. Once published there might be several input devices a user can use to fill a form, from a mobile phone to a 27" monitor.

I would like to hear your ideas on the max width a form should take on a 27" monitor if the browser window is opened in full - 3360 × 2100 / 4k.

Comment: How many columns are you using? Columns can only be so wide (especially with text) before they become unmanageable.

Comment: It should be easy to adjust with just a few lines of CSS. Start the width (of the whole form) at 40em and see how it looks. Have a media query break point set the width to 100% when the screen width is below 40em. I always use em for width units (or of course, percentages), usually a max width of 40 to 50 em. If the user has a bigger default font size set in the browser, an em will be larger, so the actual width will depend on font size, which is usually what you want.

Comment: Thanks, these thoughts are great. I am glad i am thinking in the same lines and trying to convince the product owners who are insisting everything to scale 100% (edge to edge) even on the large screens. And the font size doesnt change in views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should consider that optimal legibility principles applies to everything. A **[45 to 75 characters width is considered as good](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/balancing-line-length-font-size-responsive-web-design/#the-ideal-measure-45-to-75-characters)**, with 66 characters being optimal.

However, some research has shown this not always the case, with [**95-100cpl (characters per line) working better**](https://www.viget.com/articles/the-line-length-misconception). Also, your forms may have padding and margins, so I think that anything around *75-80cpl* should be OK

But of course, this will be influenced by font size and additional design concerns. Also, you should consider media-queries and responsive sizes. I made a quick comparison below using Arial font from 12 to 16px with 70 characters (counting spaces, as it should)

[image]

As you may see, **360px width works just fine for small fonts** , but you should consider that the **recommended minimum is 320px to cover small devices**, so counting margins you 'll need to make it even smaller. And then you can grow  to cover the most common sizes *minus* 30/40px . For example:

**290px --- 450px --- 730px** (I would stop here, so this would be the **max width for a form element**)

## Additional Resources

- [Best practices for form design](http://static.lukew.com/webforms_lukew.pdf)
- [Size Matters: Balancing Line Length And Font Size In Responsive Web Design](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/balancing-line-length-font-size-responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you need to bear in mind here. To highlight just a couple you could consider line length and flexible grids.

Depending on what literature you read, the optimum line length for reading is somewhere between 15 and 20 words - this will have some impact on the width of your form when is comes to readability.

However, there is another thing to think about (among many more). I would suggest you build your form discrete units that can be flowed into various column grids according to the width of whichever device is being used. Each unit could contain 1 or 2 fields along with their legends and and contextual instructions necessary. This can then be flowed into the page so that they automatically arrange themselves in order according to the width of the screen.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWKxz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Ultimately this is what will dictate the width of your form: font size, optimal reading length, form units/grids